# Unable to open a realm at path: open() failed: Too many open files

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, realm, android-handlerthread

I have an android application which I do many realm operations. I tried to use handler threads to faster the database operations however this time I get these errors. I have reviewed similar questions but could not find out the reason.

```
12-17 20:07:30.826  6387  8777 W System.err: io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/data/data/br.com.gomus.androidapp/files/default.realm': open() failed: Too many open files. (open("/data/data/br.com.gomus.androidapp/files/default.realm") failed: Too many open files) (/data/data/br.com.gomus.androidapp/files/default.realm) in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101 Kind: ACCESS_ERROR.
12-17 20:07:30.827  6387  8777 W System.err:    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
12-17 20:07:30.827  6387  8777 W System.err:    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.<init>(OsSharedRealm.java:184)
12-17 20:07:30.827  6387  8777 W System.err:    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:254)
12-17 20:07:30.828  6387  8777 W System.err:    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:244)
12-17 20:07:30.828  6387  8777 W System.err:    at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:319)
12-17 20:07:30.828  6387  8777 W System.err:    at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:282)
12-17 20:07:30.828  6387  8777 W System.err:    at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:332)
12-17 20:07:30.828  6387  8777 W System.err:    at br.com.gomus.androidapp.data.local.database.LocalDatabaseImpl.findRealmObject(LocalDatabaseImpl.java:284)
12-17 20:07:30.829  6387  8777 W System.err:    at br.com.gomus.androidapp.data.local.dao.schedule.SpotScheduleDaoImpl$1.run(SpotScheduleDaoImpl.java:113)
12-17 20:07:30.829  6387  8777 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:755)
12-17 20:07:30.829  6387  8777 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-17 20:07:30.829  6387  8777 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-17 20:07:30.830  6387  8777 W System.err:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This is **SpotScheduleDaoImp.java** and line 113 corresponds to the `mDatabase.findRealmObject(ScheduleCompound.class, query,` line.

```
@Override
public void find(Func1<RealmQuery<ScheduleCompound>, RealmQuery<ScheduleCompound>> query,
                 Action1<Result<List<ScheduleCompound>>> onResult) {
    if (query != null) {


        handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThreadspotscheduleDao");
        handlerThread.start();
        looper = handlerThread.getLooper();

        Handler handler = new Handler(looper);

        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Timber.log(Log.DEBUG, "find Thread.currentThread().getName() " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                mDatabase.findRealmObject(ScheduleCompound.class, query,
                        result -> {

                            onResult.call(Result.getData(SpotScheduleMapper.copyFromRealmResults(result.data)));
                            //handlerThread.quit();

                        },

                        err -> {
                            onResult.call(Result.getError(err));
                            //handlerThread.quit();

                        }
                );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is **LocalDatabaseImpl.java** and line **284** corresponds to the `realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();` command.

```
public <T extends RealmModel> void findRealmObject(Class<T> clazz,
                                                       Func1<RealmQuery<T>, RealmQuery<T>> filter,
                                                       Action1<Result<RealmResults<T>>> onResult,
                                                       Action1<Throwable> onError) {

        Realm realm = null;
        RealmResults<T> realmResults = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

            RealmQuery<T> realmQuery = filter.call(realm.where(clazz));

            Timber.log(Log.DEBUG, "findRealmObject Thread.currentThread().getName() " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            realmResults = realmQuery.findAll();

            if(realmResults.isValid()) {
                Timber.log(Log.DEBUG, clazz.getCanonicalName() + "findRealmObject realmQuery.findAll = " + realmResults);
                onResult.call(Result.getData(realmResults));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            onError.call(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(realm != null)
                if(realmResults != null && realmResults.isValid())
                    if(!realm.isClosed()) {
                        realm.close();
                    }
        }
    }
```

What I understand is something is wrong with the closing realm instances but I do not know why. Because in finally block I close the realm instance. And before that I was closing both at the end of the try and catch blocks by checking if it is not closed before like this `!realm.isClosed()` But at that time it was giving error and saying that the realm instance is already closed making it unusable. So I moved the closing part to the finally block.

This is the other stack trace.

```
--------- beginning of crash
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: MyHandlerThreadplaylistScheduleDao
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime: Process: br.com.gomus.androidapp, PID: 6387
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime: io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Too many open files in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 101
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.<init>(OsSharedRealm.java:184)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:254)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:244)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:319)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:282)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:332)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at br.com.gomus.androidapp.data.local.database.LocalDatabaseImpl.findRealmObject(LocalDatabaseImpl.java:284)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at br.com.gomus.androidapp.data.local.dao.schedule.PlaylistScheduleDaoImpl$1.run(PlaylistScheduleDaoImpl.java:110)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:755)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-17 20:07:31.796  6387  8776 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I have troubles about closing realm instances. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: in the javadoc they say that https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#getDefaultInstance-- the `getDefaultInstance()` method is a constructor... You *must* keep the first instance and reuse it. Never call that again

Comment: Realm is also Autocloseable. if you get a new instance each time you should be using try with resources so it gets closed wach time it gets instanced https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @eduyayo Thank you so much for your help. So I do not need to close it at all if I first create it using try with resources, right?

Comment: @eduyayo So should I do all my database operations with only one realm instance? Would not that be a problem when I use it with different threads?Also what if I use the realm object with UI and other background threads? Should I have different usages of it? Thanks

Comment: the doc reads: `Realm instances cannot be used across different threads. This means that you have to open an instance on each thread you want to use Realm`. So you better go with the try-with-resources stuff and transactions. You must assure the close() after use and the try with resources will do.

Comment: @eduyayo So can I remove the `close()` parts from all of them. And it would probably solve the error that too many open files, right? Also I wont need the finally block then to close the realm instance because it will be closed when it is needed.

Comment: The problem is the too many ifs... Some of them are not closed. Use the try with resources and it'll close even after an error

Comment: And use an ExecutorService to limit tha threads or you'll clog the cpu and none of them will end.

Comment: I have never used the ExecutorService before. I have used handler threads for every tasks. Do I need it still? Thanks